# How do i make div responsive with inline css

Tags: html, css

I have the situation that I can only use inline CSS because otherwise our Wordpress Theme gets all messed up. I build this little div that is suppose to be a conversion element on our articles. I now need to get it responsive for mobile devices.

all help is appreciated :)

Thats the code I have:

```html
<div style="width: 560px; height: 171px; padding: 32px 32px 0px 32px; box-shadow: 0 0.063rem 0.188rem rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 0.125rem 0.125rem rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 0 0.125rem rgba(0,0,0,0.14);">
    <div>
        <h2 style="font-family: 'Circular TT', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 700px; margin: 0px; color: #003264;">Ist Ihnen das Preis-Leistungsverhältnis für Ihren Zahnschutz wichtig?</h2>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 32px; display: block; text-align: center;">
        <button onclick="window.location.href = ;" type="submit" style="display: inline-block; color: #32ff96; background-color: #003264; border: 0.125rem solid #003264; font-family: Circular TT, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1rem; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; position: relative; width: calc(50% - 15px); padding: .625rem 1.37rem;">Ja</button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = ;" type="submit" style="display: inline-block; color: #32ff96; background-color: #003264; border: 0.125rem solid #003264; font-family: Circular TT, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1rem; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; position: relative; width: calc(50% - 15px); padding: .625rem 1.37rem; margin-left: 20px;">Nein</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: width: 90vw; max-width: 560px? This would take up 90% of the view if the screen is smaller than 560 / 0.9 pixels, or else it'll be 560 px. You could do something similar to height

Comment: but it shouldn't get messed up if you have a non-conflicting class name for the div? in which you could use css files and can use media queries for more control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your div responsive:

- Use a dynamic width value like `%` or `vh` that adjusts automatically to the screen size.
- Use `auto` value with the `height` property to adjust automatically to the div content, because the content would get longer on a narrow screen.
- you can also set a `max-width` to limit the div width on a large screen.

```
<div style="width: 95%; max-width: 560px; height: auto; min-height: 171px;">
```

Don't hesitate to reach me out for further assistance if needed.

Comment: awesome it works, had to adjust the width and padding and now it works. Thank you!!

Comment: Always glad to help :)